# Filter by taxonymy ID with multiple field in contextual filter

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

In drupal 8.9 I need to filter by taxonomy ID over multiple fields in the contextual filter of views.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

On the views edit page:

- Under Advanced: Create a relation to the field that holds the refrence to the taxonomy id ("**Taxonomy term referenced from *field_your_field_name_that_holds_the_reference***")
- Under Advanced: Create a contextual filter for the Term ID and select the previous made relation as relationship. As final step click on "more" on the same page beneith, and select allow multiple.

Now you just add multiple taxonomy id's as  1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND).

And if you want to select on multiple fields:
Repeat the process to add more fields and then you can do:

/1+2+3/877,454,453/345,345,345
Each slash represents the contextual filter field
1+2+3 is contextual filter one
877,454,453 is contextual filter two
Etc.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply but the problem is that it doesn't look clean in the url even though it's just a value i want to test.
Sorry to the time of my answer.